# How to make a class extending a jLabel so that it appears as a JLabel in my main class?

Tags: java, class, jlabel, extends

So, essentially I'm making memory. I have  a tile class, which at this point will only have a number, and a boolean (to show if it is flipped or not). I made duplicates of all the numbers as Tile objects and randomized them, and in turn added them to my layout.

Basically, I need them to show up on my screen as JLabels, and I'm not exactly sure how to do this? Should I be extending something else, or do something special in my Tile class? Or is it a problem with my logic elsewhere? Here's my Tile class at this point (very little)

PS. I also need to use a timer for the flippy flop

```
class Tile extends JLabel implements ActionListener{

boolean flipped;
int imageNum;
ImageIcon image;
JLabel card;

Tile(int num, boolean f)
{
    imageNum=num;
    flipped=f;
    card=new JLabel(""+imageNum);
}
public void flipCard()
{

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
{

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
 EDIT:

Here's the main  class where I try to add my tiles

```
JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(gridSize, gridSize));
    Tile[][]tiles=new Tile[(gridSize*gridSize)/2][2];
    boolean[][]tilePlaced=new boolean[(gridSize*gridSize)/2][2];
    JLabel[][] cardsOnGrid = new JLabel[gridSize][gridSize];
    for(int i=0;i<gridSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<gridSize;j++)
            cardsOnGrid[i][j]=new JLabel("");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<((gridSize*gridSize)/2);i++)
    {
        tiles[i][0]= new Tile(i, true);
        tiles[i][1]= new Tile(i, true);
        tilePlaced[i][0]=false;
        tilePlaced[i][1]=false;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<gridSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<gridSize;j++)
        {
            int tileNum = tileRandom(gridSize);
            int tileNumVer = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            while(tilePlaced[tileNum][tileNumVer]==true)
            {
                tileNum = tileRandom(gridSize);
                tileNumVer = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            }
            gridPanel.add(tiles[tileNum][tileNumVer]);
            tilePlaced[tileNum][tileNumVer]=true;
        }
```

:'(

Comment: Your `Tile` is already a JLabel, no need for another :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Tile(int num, boolean f){
    imageNum=num;
    flipped=f;
    card=new JLabel(""+imageNum);//1. Remove this line and card Label
    super.setText(String.valueOf(num));//ADD This line
 }
```

---

Just create `Object` of `Tile`

```
Tile myLabel = new Tile(10,false);//this will create lable
```

Because your `Tile` class is subClass of `JLabel` and no need to create `Label` in `Tile` class as `Tile` itself is a `Label`.Apart from that you won't get action events for `JLabel`.It's not a clickable element use `MouseListener`.

Comment: It's still not showing up for me, but that helps a lot, thank you

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, at this point, when I run it, simply nothing shows up on the screen

Comment: I add it later on in the code; it worked fine when I just had regular JLabels